# increment a counter variable upon repeated call of a method, PHP

Tags: php, oop

```
<html>
//index.php

<form action="" method="post"> 
  <label for="item">Item: </label>
    <select name="item">
        <option value="fruit tea">Fruit Tea</option>
         <option value="strawberries">Strawberries</option>
         <option value="coffee">Coffee</option>
    </select><br />

    <label for="qty">Qty: </label>
        <input type="text" name="qty" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>


<?php

    @$qty = $_POST['qty'];
    @$item = $_POST['item'];

    $co = new Checkout( $pricing_rules );
    print $co->scan( $item ). ' has been scanned '.$co->increment(). ' times';

?>
</html>




<?php

/**
* Description of Checkout
*
* @author cookie
*/
class Checkout {

private $pricing_rules = array();
private $pcode;
public $item;


public function __construct( array $pricing_rules ) {
    $this->pricing_rules = $pricing_rules;
}

public function scan( $item ) {

    $this->increment();
    return $item;
}

private function prod_code( $pcode ) {

    $this->pcode = $pcode;
}


public function increment() {
    static $count = 0;
    $count++;
    return $count;
}

public function total() {

}


}

?>
```

What it should be doing...

If I click the submit button four times say with strawberries selected from the dropdown. The script should print out to the screen:

strawberries has been scanned 1 times

strawberries has been scanned 2 times

strawberries has been scanned 3 times

strawberries has been scanned 4 times

etc....

With the `$count` keeping track of the incrementation.

What it actually does:

It prints:

strawberries has been scanned 2 times no matter how many times I press submit. And stops there. I'm missing something here.

I see what it's doing - upon page load, two calls to increment() take place through this line:

```
print $co->scan( $item ). ' has been scanned '.$co->increment(). ' times';
```

I tried:

```
  if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') $co->increment();
```

also, this increments $count by one, but stops there. I'm struggling a little with this..

help

Answer (score 2):

`static` variables are only static to the current script execution. Your variable is lost each time your page reloads (when you submit it). For that purpose, you need to store it in `$_SESSION`.  In fact, there's a very similar example to what you're attempting on the [`$_SESSION` basic usage manual.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php)

```
// Call session_start() at the beginning of your script...
session_start();

// And modify your method to store count in the $_SESSION.
public function increment() {
    // initialize it if not already initialized
    $_SESSION['count'] = !isset($_SESSION['count']) ? 0 : $_SESSION['count'];
    $_SESSION['count']++;
    return $_SESSION['count'];
}
```

From PHP 7.4 and higher, use the "null coalescing assignment operator" to instatiate the `count` element in the `$_SESSION` array if it is not yet declared, then `++` to increment its value (modifying its stored value) at the same time as it is returned from the method.:

```
public function increment() {
    $_SESSION['count'] ??= 0;
    return ++$_SESSION['count'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was aware of $_SESSION although not in this (OOP) context. I guess it all boils down to HTTP and it being a stateless protocol.

Comment: @AndrewCookson `$_SESSION` is a superglobal, so it can be used in any scope as long as you have initialized it.

Comment: @mickmackusa Heh - please propose an edit! When this was posted, I think PHP 5.4 was brand new and 7 features weren't but a twinkle in core dev's eyes.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you submit a form, it's making a new HTTP request to the server, and the script runs afresh.  Variables do not retain their values from one run to the next.

If you want to save variables across page reloads, you need to use session variables as Michael Berkowski suggests. However, that's just within a browser session. If you need longer retention, you can use cookies, although the user can delete these.  Finally, if you want real permanent memory, you can use a database.

The database is also appropriate if you need to combine data from multiple users. E.g. if user A scans an item and then user B scans the item, and you want to display the combined total.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Michael Berkowski's answer I'd like to point out something else. Why declaring the `$counter` in a function if it's supposed to be an *object* field. And as it's supposed to be an *object* field, then why `static`? If it's static it will count for all instances of `Checkout` at a given point.
Also you call once `increment()` in `scan()` internally and then you call it again

```
print $co->scan( $item ). ' has been scanned '.$co->increment(). ' times';
//         ^ here $counter == 1                       ^ and here $counter == 2
```

**Add**
Something like this would make more sense for me

```
class Checkout{

    private $counter;


    public __construct(){
        $this->counter = 0;
        // ......
    }
    // ..... 

    public function scan(){
        // ....
        $this->counter++;
    }

    public function getCounter(){
        $return $this->counter;
    }

}
```

Comment: Indeed, makes one think a little doesn't it. The code you show was merely a test to get some throughput for my own sanity really. But hey, I'm listening.

Comment: Cool, as Michael Berkowski and Barmar did beat me to it, for the "first" part of the answer, that was my twopence for the rest of it :)

Comment: Now added some exemplary code as an idea on the OOP side in general, not in a stateless HTTP environment ;)